# Azure devops for Python

Tags: python, flask, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to create an azure ci/cd pipeline for my python application. I have tried many ways but not get success. I can create CI successfully even in some cases cd also but not able to see the output on the azure app service.

I use Linux app services that use the Python 3.7 version.

I can create ci-cd successfully using the YAML file but I want to create using the classic editor without YAML, as I have some restrictions using yaml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will post the steps I deploy a simple hello world project with DevOps CI/CD pipeline.

**1. Create pipeline:**
[image]
[image]
[image]
**2. Create Release pipeline:**
[image]
[image]
3. **Save and queue your pipeline**, the release pipeline would be triggered. Here is the file structure on Azure KUDU:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Working as expected. I missed the install requirement command, added as you suggested and woked.

Comment: can you tell me what changes i have to do to include test cases as well.