# Publishing using MSDeploy to Azure App from a different computer updates all the files

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy, msdeploy

Currently in the process of potentially moving our sites to Azure.  As it stands we are testing deploying to Azure app service, everything works and publishes fine using one computer.  However if someone else runs a publish from a different computer with an identical build the publish operation sees fit to 'update' all of the files, of which there are a lot.  Then when the next publish occurs from the original computer the same happens there.  Further publishes from the same computer do not generate this 'updating' of all the files which takes a long time.

Never had this issue previously when publishing to IIS on our Rackspace servers.  Why is MSDeploy choosing to update these files even though they have not changed at all and seemingly only because the publish is coming from a different computer to the last publish that occurred?

Can anyone explain how I can stop this?

Comment: Use Azure Devops release pipeline.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it, although from a cursory look it seems overkill for simply wanting to avoid updating files that haven't changed when publishing from different computers.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your project is in local repository or personal repository, and maybe published using zip deploy or Visual Studio.

> Deploy like that would come up with a connection between Azure and the
> location of your project. If you deploy from another computer, or
> another repository, the connection would be fresh to the new one,
> which would update all the files like publishing a new project.

You could consider **deploying continuously** from a remote repository like GitHub, which you could access it on any computer.

**Here are the samples you could have a look:**

[Deploy using GitHub Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66540187/13586071)

[Deploy using DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64783120/13586071)