# Gunicorn Worker Fails to Boot on Azure Web App Linux - ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, gunicorn

I am facing an issue with deploying a Django application on Azure Web App Linux using Gunicorn. The deployment process appears to be successful, but the Gunicorn worker fails to boot with the following error:

```
[2024-03-08 07:32:30 +0000] [71] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
...
2024-03-08T07:32:38.548081541Z ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validator'
...
```

`csvvalidator` is the Django project name and `validator` is the app name. The folder looks like this

```
- csvvalidator/
    - csvvalidator/
        wsgi.py
        setting.py
        ...
    - validator/
        __init__.py
        ...
    - manage.py
    ...
```

Also in settings.py I have `validator` in `INSTALLED_APPS`. Any guidance or insights on resolving this Gunicorn worker boot failure would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the folder structure. Kudu needs a certain folder structure, I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534333/deploying-django-web-app-using-devops-ci-cd-onto-azure-app-service/66540187#66540187) to guide me.

The solution was to delete the outermost `cssvalidator` folder.

Answer (score 0):

As per the doc [ModuleNotFoundError when app starts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-language-python#modulenotfounderror-when-app-starts), this error most often occurs if you deploy your virtual environment with your code. Virtual environment shouldn't be deployed with your application code.

You could exclude `!venv/**` from your zip file.

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: |
      $(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/**
      !venv/**
      !.git/**
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: |
      $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: 'zip'
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
    replaceExistingArchive: true
```

In addition, for app setting, you should set `SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT`to 1.

please also check if 'csvvalidator.validator.wsgi' is part of your Django project, ensure that it’s correctly referenced.

Comment: I tried this and got a different error, now associated with wsgi file. Please check the updated question.

Comment: @LLM_Enthusiast, for the new error, does this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39460892/gunicorn-no-module-named-myproject) help?

Comment: Yes, the problem was the structure of the folders. Thank you. I used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66534333/deploying-django-web-app-using-devops-ci-cd-onto-azure-app-service/66540187#66540187)